# PHP inserting some text before and after a string

Tags: php, string, insert

I'm pretty new to PHP and have a String which contains an HTML page. I'd need to insert some custom code BEFORE and AFTER any **HR** HTML tag. Example:

```
    <html>
    ....
     <p>INSERT HERE</p> 
     <hr class="pagebreak">
     <p>INSERT HERE</p> 

     <p>INSERT HERE</p> 
     <hr class="pagebreak">
     <p>INSERT HERE</p> 
    ....
    </html>
```

I've tried with several combinations of **preg_replace** and **substr_replace**, however I still couldn't manage to insert the custom code in all places I need.
Anybody can help me to solve this puzzle ?
P.s. I need to use PHP standard String functions- I cannot use any HTML parsing library since I don't have control over the PHP libraries available on the server.
Thanks a lot
Linda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to get is good regular expression, assuming that you managed to get it work at least partially, you propably had bad expression (example would help). I tested this code for you and it should work on all your `<hr>`s:

```
$newtext=preg_replace("#(<hr[^>]*>)#s",$yourprefix."\${1}".$yoursuffix,$oldtext);
```

variable oldtext is what you had before, new text is what you want, and prefix and suffix is what you want to add around hr tag

Comment: Thank you very much, both your solution and and inhan workerd perfectly. Sorry I have just built my profile so I cannot add you any score for your reply :-(

Comment: No problem, at least you got solution, just notice the difference, my expression works even if `<hr>` takes multiple lines, however it is case sensitive so it wont work for `<HR>`, if you want to change it, just put `#i` at the end instead

Answer (score 1):

```
$before = '<p>Before the hr tag</p>';
$after = '<p>After the hr tag</p>';

$str = preg_replace('/(<hr(.*?)>)/i',$before.'$1'.$after,$str);
```

Comment: Thank you also for your great suggestion inhan !